# How to replace comma separated array in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I would like to know how to replace my comma separated array to another comma separated array in mysql database. Have any method to replace without getting values from database only insert method.

Example:

`X` table `Y` column have this comma separated array: `1,3,2,6,3,4` I want to change this `3,2,6` values to `5,8,9`. Finally array should be `1,5,8,9,3,4` in database.

I want to it without getting data from mysql database and also without giving privies value which means without giving `3,2,6`. That means update this array from 2nd value of array. If it is not possible, please give me another possible method.

Comment: Sounds like a bad design pattern. Storing comma separated values is generally a bad idea.

Comment: What would you suggest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/4535200

Answer (score 0):

Of course, comma separated arrays are just text strings as far as the database is concerned.  So you can do this to make the change you want.

```
 UPDATE X SET Y = REPLACE(Y,'3,2,6','5,8,9') WHERE Y = '1,3,2,6,3,4'
```

Generally speaking, putting comma-separated values in single SQL columns makes it hard to update those columns, or search for values, in any SQL-friendly fashion.

Comment: but this code also want to get Y values." Y = '1,3,2,6,3,4'"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `MySQL` doesn't have something like `REGEXP_REPLACE` function, so manipulating strings containing comma-separated lists is quite tricking task.

For your particular case you could use this:

`UPDATE X SET Y = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM
  REPLACE(CONCAT(',', Y, ','), ',<SRC>,', ',<DST>,')
) WHERE ...;`

Replacing `<SRC>` and `<DST>` with your `3,2,6` and `5,8,9` respectively, you'll get desired result.

Comment: please give me update code for this. Without using 3,2,6. How to give update from 2nd value of array

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question